# Trying to run syncdb in the django tutorial and getting error

Tags: django, django-syncdb

```
~/Documents/django1/mysite$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/home/nick/Documents/django1/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 15
    'NAME': '/home/nick/Documents/django1/sqlite.db'
```

Settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
        'NAME': '/home/nick/Documents/django1/sqlite3.db' # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',    # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '', # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
      ^
```

Comment: Show your `DATABASES` dict from `settings.py`. The problem is there.

Comment: I added it to the notes above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing commas (after the `ENGINE` and `NAME` items) in your `DATABASES` dict:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/nick/Documents/django1/sqlite3.db', # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',    # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '', # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```